# Meaning of チキチキツアー?

Tags: meaning

In a novel (published around 2009) a person suggests to search several abandoned buildings and this is how the other person responds:

> -- で？　おれといっしょに廃墟を探検しようっていうチキチキツアーのお誘いか？

I struggle to pinpoint the meaning of "チキチキツアー". It feels like a reference to something (a book / tv show / a music band?), however I did not manage to find anything in google that would make sense in this context.  Another thought: it might be an imitation of a sound, like clock's ticking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ultimate origin of チキチキ is [*Chitty Chitty Bang Bang*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chitty_Chitty_Bang_Bang) (1968; チキチキバンバン in Japanese). The "Chitty Chitty" part was somehow reused in the name of the Japanese adoption of [*Wacky Races*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wacky_Races_(1968_TV_series)). See [チキチキマシン猛レース](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%81%E3%82%AD%E3%83%81%E3%82%AD%E3%83%9E%E3%82%B7%E3%83%B3%E7%8C%9B%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9) (1970). The program became popular, and many parodies were created. Since then, Japanese people started to vaguely recognize チキチキ as a prefix randomly added to things related to races, competitions or "going forward", hence チキチキツアー. Today, チキチキ has no specific meaning except that it makes the name sound like a variety show on TV.

See also: [「チキチキ」の意味と使い方・語源](https://tap-biz.jp/lifestyle/word-meaning/1031934)

Comment: Wow, that's quite an origin. This explains why I got confused by the sheer variety of search results. Many thanks for the comprehensive explanation, this was very helpful!